# Why does the ifelse function return only the first element of a vector provided as an argument?

Tags: r

I was puzzled by the result of the following R code:

```
ifelse(TRUE, c(2, 3, 4), "a")
#[1] 2
```

The result is `2`, but I expected to be `2, 3, 4`. Why is this?

Comment: From the help `?ifelse`:  "ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the element of test is TRUE or FALSE." I think this is to say that if your test is a vector of length one (like your `TRUE`) it returns a value of length one too.   Try replacing `TRUE` with `c(TRUE,TRUE)` to see this demonstrated.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: @JonSpring, please post that as an answer!  hugo, we don't need the screenshot in addition to your perfectly intelligible text-based question ... (we believe you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the help `?ifelse`:

> "ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
> with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
> element of test is TRUE or FALSE."

I think this is to say that if your test is a vector of length one (like your TRUE) it returns a value of length one too. If the test has a length of two, it'll return a value of length two. (Recycling the elements of the designated value, if necessary.)

```
> ifelse(TRUE, c(2,3,4), "a")
[1] 2
> ifelse(c(TRUE,TRUE), c(2,3,4), "a")
[1] 2 3
> ifelse(c(FALSE,FALSE), c(2,3,4), "a")
[1] "a" "a"
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should post data and code as text and not as an image.

Second `ifelse` is used for vectors (that has length > 1) for scalars (length = 1) use `if`/`else`.

```
if(TRUE) c(2, 3, 4) else 'a'
#[1] 2 3 4

if(FALSE) c(2, 3, 4) else 'a'
#[1] "a"
```