# ifelse assignment does not return pre-defined character vector

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, character, variable-assignment

I cannot figure out why an `ifelse` assignment does not return the entire object I'm trying to pass.

Below, I look to see if the state of Texas is in a vector of state names (in my actual code, I'm looking up unique state names in a shapefile). Then, if Texas is in this list of state names, assign to a new object (states_abb) the abbreviations for Texas and New Mexico. Otherwise, assign to states_abb the abbreviations for California and Nevada.

I know from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427983/why-does-the-ifelse-function-return-only-the-first-element-of-a-vector-provided) and `?ifelse` that...

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
> with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
> element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

So in my first example below, I can understand that only CA is returned.

```
states <- c("California", "Nevada")
(states_abb <- ifelse("Texas" %in% states, c("NM", "TX"), c("CA", "NV")))
# [1] "CA"
```

But in this second example below, I've pre-defined the object canv_abb. Why doesn't that whole object get passed? Even if it's a character vector, it's its own object, right? Shouldn't that whole "package" get passed?

```
txnm_abb <- c("NM", "TX")
canv_abb <- c("CA", "NV")
(states_abb <- ifelse("Texas" %in% states, txnm_abb, canv_abb))
# [1] "CA"
```

I appreciate any insights as to why this is happening. And can someone offer a solution so that I can assign BOTH abbreviations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` is the wrong tool here. You use `ifelse` when you have a *vector* of logical tests and you wish to create a new vector *of the same length*. You have a *single* logical test, but want your output to be a vector.

What you are describing is better handled by an `if` and `else` clause:

```r
states_abb <- if("Texas" %in% states) txnm_abb else canv_abb

states_abb
#> [1] "CA" "NV"
```

To try to get a feel for how `ifelse` works, consider the following input and output:

```r
condition <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
input1    <- c("A", "b", "C")
input2    <- c("1", "2", "3")

result <- ifelse(condition, input1, input2)

result
#> [1] "A" "2" "3"
```

You will see that `ifelse` is a vectorized, shorthand way of writing the following loop, which is a pattern that comes up surprisingly often in data wrangling:

```r
result <- character(3)

for(i in 1:length(condition)) {
  result[i] <- if(condition[i]) input1[i] else input2[i]
}

result
#> [1] "A" "2" "3"
```

Note though that this is *not* what you are trying to do in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is 'same length'. If you apply `ifelse` both the input and output must have same length. In your case it is 1:2. In this case only the first will be calculated.

See `?ifelse`:
'`ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as test"

solution use a classic if else structure:

```
states <- c("California", "Nevada")

states_abb <- if ("Texas" %in% states) {
  c("NM", "TX")
} else {
  c("CA", "NV")
}
```

```
> states_abb
[1] "CA" "NV"
```